# Is there a reduction formula for $I_n=\int_{0}^{n\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I haven't been able to manipulate this integral. I need to find the value of $I_n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ and arrange them in ascending order.

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate the integrals? Or do you only need to arrange them in ascending order?

Comment: @mickep Just arrange them, but I would still need an approximation wouldn't I?

Comment: You do not need to approximate, but rather to estimate. I suggest that you look at the sign of $\sin x$. Where is it positive? Where negative? What does that mean for your integrals? Also, note that the function $x\mapsto 1/(1+x)$ is _decreasing_.

Comment: Make a qualitative plot of the integrand, compare areas following @mickep comment and use the definition of integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sine function oscillates with zeros at integer multiples of $\pi$, we introduce
$$
K_j=\int_{(j-1)\pi}^{j\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+x}\,dx,\quad j\in\{1,2,3,4\}.
$$
Then, since $x\mapsto 1/(1+x)$ is decreasing and since $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$ we find that
$$
K_1>-K_2>K_3>-K_4>0.
$$
The integrals we want to compare are given by
$$
I_1=K_1,\quad I_2=K_1+K_2,\quad I_3=K_1+K_2+K_3,\quad I_4=K_1+K_2+K_3+K_4,
$$
I stop here, and suggest you to try to conclude from the facts above that the correct order is

> $$I_2<I_4<I_3<I_1$$

As suggested in the comments, it might be good to have a picture:

[image: sine]